# optional react useState types with jsdoc, typescript checkjs (javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsdoc

using typescript's jsdoc support to type the following **javascript** code:

```
const [optionalNumber, setOptionalNumber] = useState(null)

const handleClick = () => {
  setOptionalNumber(42) 
  //          ^-- Argument of type '42' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<null>'
}
```

the way i currently get around this works but is a bit ugly:

```
const [optional, setOptional] = useState(
  /** @type {number|null} */ (null)
)
```

how can i accomplish this without using casting? i want `optional` to have a type of `null | number`, and `setOptional` to only accept `null | number` as an argument.

codesandbox demonstrating this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-villani-kbudi?fontsize=14

Comment: Just use undefined instead of null: `const [optional, setOptional] = useState()`

Comment: i still want this limited to {null|number} - useState with no args results in optional being `any`

Comment: updated with more context about this

Comment: It's not currently possible... there is an open issue for it: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27387

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can define an initial value with the correct union type and pass it to `useState`.

It would be something like this:

```
/**
* @type {number | null}
*/
const initValue = 42;
const [optionalNumber, setOptionalNumber] = useState(initValue)
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that your component relies on the inital state of the `optional` state being the `null` value (rather than `undefined`), one solution would be to explicitly specify the state hooks type as a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) of both `number` and `null` like so:

```
// Allows initial value to be null, and number to be subsequently set 
const [optional, setOptional] = useState<number | null>(null);

// optional === null

setOptional(42);
```

Alternatively, if your component does not distingush between `undefined` or `null` for the inital `optional` state value, then the following would work:

```
const [optional, setOptional] = useState<number>();

// optional === undefined

setOptional(42);
```

Comment: sorry I wrote the question poorly, I'm looking to solve this in javascript, not typescript (I'm using typescript's checkjs feature)